# Eclipse: APP can't access the internet

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My main class look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.internetview);

  String url = "https://www.google.de";
  WebView view =(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

  view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

and my internetview.xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If i have the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in my Manifest the WebView is permanently white... and without this line the WebView show the Error cant find or acces the internet.

The crazy thing is that the Emulator browser work normaly.

Comment: Is your device connected to the wifi/3g network? Can you access the web using your browser app?

Comment: Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: Yes it is connected "The crazy thing is that the Emulator browser work normaly". Ok I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has worked for me, where I start a new activity and have this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView mWebView=new WebView(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    setContentView(mWebView);
}
```

Comment: The first option don't wortk(Exception). But the second on works! Thank you soooo much:)

Comment: Glad the second option worked. I'll edit out the first one for any future people wondering how to do the same thing. Note that the _.getSettings().set_________ functions are not technically required, and the ones I listed do not cover all situations. See [the webSettings documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) for more.